# Использование одного bitrix инфоблока новостей для разных страниц

Tags: php, битрикс, компоненты

Есть страница новостей site.ru/news где отображаются все новости, используется news.list и news.detail для отображения соответственно всех и детальной(детальная отображается на новой странице с отображением шапки и футера сайта).
Так же есть в рамках сайта раздел(site.ru/super-news) где свой(другой) дизайн и там идёт отображение выборки новостей для этого раздела, использую тот же информационный блок и компоненты, выборку делаю result_modifier'om, но страница детальная новости открывается на основном сайте(с его шапкой и футером), нужно чтобы открывалась в разделе(site.ru/super-news/news1)

Передачу урла сделал, sef_params юзал, urlrewrite тоже пробовал но всё время открывает основной сайт с 404 страницей.
Реально ли использовать один информационный блок под разные страницы для детального просмотра(общий список реально как выяснилось)? делал всё в аналогии как с основой

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы детальная страница открывалась правильно, нужно заполнить параметр DETAIL_URL, иначе детальная страница берётся из настроек инфоблока.
2. Выборку не нужно делать через result_modifier. Нужно в /super-news/index.php сделать выборку, получить список ID, сформировать фильтр и передать его в параметре FILTER_NAME.

Comment: с этой проблемой разобрался - неверно добавлял элемент в urlrewrite, теперь вопрос другой
после первого перехода на детальную страницу всё окей но после нажатия обновить страницу слетают стили, куда копать в данном случае, не подскажите?

Comment: Вероятно, проблема с кэшированием. Смотрите здесь: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/vad/1820.php